# How to fix "Number is larger than maximum" in smartSVN

Tags: svn, smartsvn

I want check out my online repository with smartSVN, but I always get a the following cryptic error when checking out the entire repo. I've tried to check out a subfolder from this repo and that works.

[image]

I did not find any description of this error in the SVN manual.

Can someone tell me how to fix this? Is it possible that my repository is too large?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Please try the clone with command line SVN -- do you see the same error there?

Comment: Hi mstrap, tried it now and it does not help me.. do you have a another idea? should i try to update my smartSVN? Maybe it will fix it

Comment: Which (Smart)SVN version are you using? Yes, please try with SmartSVN 9.3 and/or command line SVN 1.9.

Comment: Thanks you for the feedback!, I dated the smartVersion now up and it did not helped. I copied now the repository by hand and did not a checkout... with this  workaround is everything working. Thanks for your time!